# embed.fields[1].value: Must be 1024 or fewer in length. embed.fields[2].value: Must be 1024 or fewer in length

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating an event for `messageUpdate`, and everything is working "perfectly" fine, except when someone sends a message that contains more than 1024 characters, it returns an error as `addField` has a character limit.
How could I possibly make the bot send an error if the message that has been edited has reached the limit ?

```js
if(oldMessage.cleanContent.length >= 1000) return channel.send("Too long");
if(newMessage.cleanContent.length >= 1000) return channel.send("Too long");

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .addField("Old Message", `${oldMessage.cleanContent}`, true)
   .addField("New Message", `${newMessage.cleanContent}`, true)
channel.send(embed)
```

Comment: Both those `if` statements at the beginning don't help ?

Comment: Don't worry about it. I figured it out! :)

Comment: and what was wrong ?

Comment: I had to do `const oldMessageContent = oldMessage.cleanContent` then create an `if` statement and set it equals to `oldMessageContent.length`

Answer (score 1):

(Posting this message so the question can get answered)

Judging from what you posted in the comments, this *should* be right. (I'm not the greatest dev so, feel free to yell at me if it's wrong)

```js
const oldMessage = oldMessage.cleanContent
const newMessage = newMessage.cleanContent

if (oldMessageContent.length >= 1000) return channel.send("Too long");
if (newMessageContent.length >= 1000) return channel.send("Too long");

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .addField("Old Message", `${oldMessage.cleanContent}`, true)
   .addField("New Message", `${newMessage.cleanContent}`, true)
channel.send(embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a loop to add more fields for every 1024 characters

**Example:**

```js
for (let i = 0; i < oldMessage.cleanContent.length; i += 2000) {
    const cont = oldMessage.cleanContent.substring(i, Math.min(oldMessage.cleanContent.length, i + 2000));
    embed.addField("Old Message", cont);
}

for (let i = 0; i < newMessage.cleanContent.length; i += 2000) {
    const cont = newMessage.cleanContent.substring(i, Math.min(newMessage.cleanContent.length, i + 2000));
    embed.addField("New Message", cont);
}
```